# MYSQL smart parking populair time

Tags: mysql

For an assignment I’m working on a Smart Parking solution using MySQL database. Now I have a challenge where I hope you can give me some tips. 
What I want to do is to calculate the average time the parking lot is ‘occupied’ per hour based on my MySQL database.

Now in the database I only have data when the changes did happen. So I do not have the data per hour and I’m struggling to calculate an average time occupied per hour.

```
Timestamp                 parkFlag
2018-09-10 01:13:23       1
2018-09-10 07:57:34       0
2018-09-10 10:02:28       1
2018-09-10 15:20:01       0
2018-09-10 15:37:13       1
2018-09-11 08:10:54       0
2018-09-11 09:51:27       1
2018-09-11 11:35:35       0
2018-09-11 13:28:31       1
2018-09-12 07:30:28       0
2018-09-12 12:00:10       1
2018-09-12 12:08:13       0
2018-09-12 12:33:04       1
2018-09-12 12:33:58       0
2018-09-12 15:26:49       1
```

ParkFlag 1 = Car parked,
Parkflag 0 = Car left

In order to extract data I tried:

```
SELECT ts
      ,parkFlag
      ,hour(ts)
      ,SUM(secsOccu)
      ,AVG(parkFlag) AS avgParkflag 
FROM -database- 
WHERE (ts >= '2018-09-10 00:00:00' 
AND ts <= '2018-09-12 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY hour(ts)
```

Results in the following MySQL output:

```
ts                   parkFlag    hour(ts)    SUM(secsOccu)      avgParkFlag
2018-09-10 01:13:23  1          1           0                   1.0000
2018-09-10 07:57:34  0          7           400                 0.0000
2018-09-11 08:10:54  0          8           1202                0.0000
2018-09-11 09:51:27  1          9           0                   1.0000
2018-09-10 10:02:28  1          10          0                   1.0000
2018-09-11 11:35:35  0          11          6239                0.0000
2018-09-12 12:08:13  0          12          15484               0.3333
2018-09-11 13:28:31  1          13          0                   1.0000
2018-09-10 15:20:01  0          15          19048               0.6667
```

However it doesn’t take into account that the parking lot was occupied between 6 and 7 (on 2018-09-10).
So what I would like is to get out resulting in:

```
Time              occupied 
[…]               […]
06:00 – 07:00     66%
07:00 – 08:00     81,67%
08:00 – 09:00     5,33%
etc.
```

However I got no clue how to do this?

Comment: You will need to use a Master table having all the dates to consider and hour ranges to consider.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That is one option.

Comment: How do we know that the parking lot was occupied between 6 & 7 !?!

Comment: A car arrived at 01:13:23 (parkflag > 1) and left at 07:57:34 (parkflag > 0). Meaning the car was parked between 6:00 and 7:00

Comment: If you don't '@user' commentators, then they don't see your replies (except by chance)